# How to make custom function for jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

How does one go about making a custom function to append to the jQuery selector? Something that would look like:

```
$('.my_class').my_function();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to add the function to `jQuery.fn` (which is a reference to the jQuery object prototype). For more details check out:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

An example\stub:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.my_function = function(){ ... };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: i'm willing to bet this question is a duplicate :-\

Comment: I would have thought so too, which is why I did check first :)

Comment: This is great! D'ya by any chance know of a vanilla.js way of writing this so that if your project doesn't have JQuery, it won't throw any errors? I realise that it won't work either, but I want to add it to the "universal-functions.js" file that I throw into all my projects.