# How to create a JQuery selector function?

Tags: jquery

How can I create a function / constructor (not sure how to call it) that is integrated with Jquery selector.

For example:

```
$('some selector').myFunction();
```

Where 'some selector' is any normal selector, and `myFunction` is a function that runs on these elements.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/

Comment: @PranavCBalan Not what I needed but indeed very useful information for the future.

Comment: I'm almost certain this question is a duplicate of [How to make custom function for jQuery selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644896/how-to-make-custom-function-for-jquery-selector)

Comment: @DJDavid98 Probably, I just didn't find the right WORDS to ask.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/wbQjkHn.png

Comment: Umm this is sad, I must be tired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a jQuery plugin. Thyere is a simple tutorial on the jQuery site at http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/.

Comment: Aaaah Plugin! That's the word I was suppose to be looking for!

This should do it. thanks.